# Copying cells to an array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I am attempting to increase the array *arrSpecificWS* as I copy ranges from worksheet wsTemp. I am getting an *Subscript out of range*  error on the ***ReDim Preserve arrSpecificWS(UBound(arrSpecificWS, 1) + 1)*** line. What am I missing ?

```
Dim I as  long
Dim arrSpecificWS()

 'Prepare data to the array
  ReDim arrSpecificWS(0, 1 To 6)



For i = 2 To wsTemp.UsedRange.Rows.count
   arrSpecificWS(UBound(arrSpecificWS), 1) = wsTemp.Range("D2" & i).Value
   arrSpecificWS(UBound(arrSpecificWS), 2) = wsTemp.Range("E2" & i).Value
   ReDim Preserve arrSpecificWS(UBound(arrSpecificWS, 1) + 1)
   ReDim Preserve arrSpecificWS(UBound(arrSpecificWS, 2) + 1)

Next i
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847284/subscript-out-of-range-with-redim-vba

Comment: Would that mean you cant use Preserve on multidimensional arrays?

Comment: You can, but You can only change one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a shortened version of your code? If not, and you are simply adding a range to an array, why bother looping over the range and assigning values one cell at a time? You can set an array by assigning a range to it like this:

```
Dim arrRange() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
arrRange = Range("D2:E" & wsTemp.UsedRange.Rows.count)
```

This is much quicker and then you don't have to monkey with redimming arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Tim , The code above is a portion of a code I am writing. I wanted to differentiate where each cell goes so I can manipulate the cell based on certain criteria. The following actually worked for what I am dealing with.

Comment: For i = 2 To wsTemp.UsedRange.Rows.count
          ReDim Preserve outerArrData(2 To i)
    
         arrSpecificWS(1) = wsTemp.Cells(i, 4).Value 
         arrSpecificWS(2) = wsTemp.Cells(i, 5).Value
         arrSpecificWS(3) = wsTemp.Cells(i, 6).Value  
     
    
        outerArrData(i) = arrSpecificWS

 
      Next i